# Diffing lines in the wrong position

Tags: bug, edits

So went to check out [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25608086/revisions) and saw that the formatting is all wonky.

Chrome on Mac OSX.

> [image: weird diff formatting]
>   <sup>Sorry for the large screenshot; it was the only way to show all of the formatting.</sup>

Is this on my end? I've left the page and come back to have the same thing happen, so it wasn't a one-off type of thing.

Comment: I can see it too.

Comment: I can see it on Chrome, but IE and Firefox are clear.

Comment: Looks fine on Firefox.

Comment: I bet IE is overly proud for not having an issue when other browsers are.

Comment: It looks fine to me, Chrome on Win7.

Comment: What version are you running, @eddie_cat? I'm on Chrome 36 with no plugins on Windows 7, and mine's as broken as the image.

Comment: @Kendra I'm also on Chrome 36 w/o plugins. Weird.

Comment: @eddie_cat Very. Are you looking at the side-by-side markdown view? I didn't see anything odd until I switched to that view. If so... You are special and get a cookie.

Comment: @Kendra I see it now. No cookie for me. :(

Comment: (N.m. earlier cmt) *Refreshing* the page makes it wonky on my iPad's Safari as well.

Comment: No repro with IE 11 on Windows RT 8.1.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just you, there is a discrepancy with how browsers are handling blank spaces when the container has the CSS property `white-space: pre-wrap`

Here is a relevant question - [google chrome bug with pre-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676036/google-chrome-bug-with-pre-wrap)

The answer:

> I'd say Chrome is the only browser correctly following [W3C recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model).
>
> Look at the second point 4
>
> If spaces (U+0020) or tabs (U+0009) at the end of a line have
> **'white-space' set to 'pre-wrap', UAs may visually collapse them**.

Indeed, setting `white-space` to `pre` fixes this in Chrome and breaks it horribly in Firefox :D

## Chrome

[image: Chrome]

## Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Comment: I'm so sorry chrome, I shouldn't have doubted you!!